# Select2 - Loading options

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Is there any native method to add a loader inside a select2, while loading options through ajax?

Comment: if you are using ajax then try to add a class `loader` when `.ajaxStart()` and remove it when `.ajaxComplete()`

Comment: Since there's no native method or param to add a loader, that point of view seems to be a good alternative! Thanks jai